# Add multiple datasets in rdlc in vs 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, rdlc

I am trying to add multiple datasets to my rdlc in vs 2005. In vs 2010, we have an option called 'Report Data' window, from there, we can add multiple datasets. But, in vs 2005, i am not finding that option. Pls suggest me, how can i add multiple datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2005, when "editing" a report, there are three tabs above the report designer. The leftmost tab is to manage the data sources, the rightmost tab shows a report preview.

Switch to the leftmost tab and add new data sources using the controls there.

[image]